# How to imitate slow connection with servlet

Tags: servlets

How I can configure servlet to response with some delay for GET or POST, without using Thread.sleep()?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.wait()`:

```
synchronized (this) { this.wait (1000); }
```

These are the only two ways to wait in Java. Everything else will finally use `sleep()` or `wait()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do some CPU-intensive task, like calculating Pi with a high precision or a factorial of a big number.